# Easiest way to find the screen resolution of all machines on a windows network?

Tags: windows, networking, screen-resolution

I'd rather not run round checking each machine individually, is there some server-side software I can use? It's a mixed linux/windows network (clients and servers) but I'm only interested in the windows clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mh for the link to WMI. Here's the script I ended up with.

```
On Error resume next

strDomain = "domain.local"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if err.number <> 0 then Wscript.quit

set domObj = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain)
domObj.Filter = Array("computer")
For Each objComputer In domObj
    err.clear
    strComputer = objComputer.Name
    computerName = "UNKNOWN"
    loggedOnUser =""
    sp = ""
    ram = ""
    cpu = ""
    cpuMhz = ""
    xres = ""
    yres = ""

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    if err.number=0 then
    ' Query "BIOS" properties
    ' computer name
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_BIOS")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        computerName = objItem.Path_.Server
    Next

    ' Query Processor properties
    ' Family
    ' ...
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Processor")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        cpu = objItem.Manufacturer & " " & objItem.Name
        cpuMhz = objItem.MaxClockSpeed
    Next

    ' Query Operating System properties
    ' SP Level
    ' RAM
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        sp = objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion
        ram = objItem.TotalVisibleMemorySize
    Next

    ' Query Computer System properties
    ' User
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        loggedOnUser = objItem.UserName
    Next

    ' Query Display properties
    ' Screen resolution
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DisplayConfiguration")
        For Each objItem in colItems
            xres = objItem.PelsWidth
            yres = objItem.PelsHeight
        Next

        strFile = "\\server\data\inventory\" & computerName & ".txt"

        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 2, True)
        if err.number <> 0 then Wscript.quit

        objTextFile.WriteLine("Computer Name: " & strComputer)
        if err.number <> 0 then Wscript.quit

    if loggedOnUser <> "" then objTextFile.WriteLine("User: " & loggedOnUser)
    if cpu <> "" then objTextFile.writeLine("CPU: " & cpu)
    if cpuMhz <> "" then objTextFile.writeLine("CPU MHZ: " & cpuMhz)
    if ram <> "" then objTextFile.WriteLine("RAM: " & ram)
    if sp <> "" then objTextFile.WriteLine("Service Pack: " & sp)
    if xres <> "" then objTextFile.WriteLine("Horizontal resolution: " & xres)
    if yres <> "" then objTextFile.WriteLine("Vertical resolution: " & yres)

        objTextFile.Close

    end if
next
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows clients you can use a WMI script to obtain this.  The info [here](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/21/how-can-i-determine-the-current-screen-resolution-being-used-on-a-computer.aspx) should help get you started.

Comment: Looks good, but how do I get it to run on all client machines in the domain and report back to me?

Comment: Have a script run at logon that outputs the results to a text file (named with the client computer's name.txt) with the results to a everyone-write-access share?

Comment: It should be easy enough to adapt once you have a list of computer names to start with.  Loop through the list and call a sub containing most of the code in that link.  Results could go to a file share, be sent via email or logged to a database.  But we're getting more into the realm of "how to write VBScript" here, which is probably better covered in a separate question once you've made a decision on which way to go.

Comment: @mh not really. I know how to write VBScript, but I don't know WMI. What I really meant was "how to run at logon", but I've figured that out. What I didn't realise is that you can do this from one machine given a list of the other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via SCOM but it's a big hammer to crack a small nut to be honest.